# Can we take the gravitational forces between two bodies which are not spheres along their center of mass?

Tags: newtonian-gravity

I know we can treat the mass of a sphere to be at the center by Newton's shell theorem (modified) but what about other objects like square or other random shapes?

Comment: The general answer is that no, for a general object you can *not* assume the mass is in the center. It is only valide for a sphere. If you can approsimate the object with a sphere decently enough, that you can go around it but that's it!

Answer (score 0):

If the two bodies are small compared to the distance between them, then we can get a pretty good approximation of the net forces they exert on each other by treating them as point masses located at their respective centers of mass.  It won't be exactly correct, but the larger the ratio of their distance to their sizes, the better the approximation will be.

For starters, let's consider a point mass $\mu$ a long distance away from a non-spherical object A.  If we wanted to find the *exact* force on this point mass, we'd have to mentally divide up the object A into constituent particles, find the force on $M$ due to each one of them, and add them all up (as vectors):
$$
\vec{F} = -\sum_\alpha \frac{G \mu m_\alpha}{r_\alpha^2} \hat{r}_\alpha
$$
where the index $\alpha$ runs over all of the particles in A, $m_\alpha$ is the mass of each particle, $r_\alpha$ is the distance from $\mu$ to each respective particle, and $\hat{r}_\alpha$ is a vector pointing from each particle to $\mu$.

Normally this sum would be very hard to do.  (It'd usually be treated as an integral over the volume of $A$.)  But if $\mu$ is very very far from the object $A$, then the distances $r_\alpha$ between $\mu$ and each of the particles in $A$ are all pretty much equal, and all of the vectors $\hat{r}_\alpha$ point pretty much in the same direction.  This means that we have
$$
\vec{F} \approx - \frac{G \mu}{r^2} \hat{r} \sum_\alpha m_\alpha = -\frac{G \mu M_A}{r^2} \hat{r}
$$
where $r$ is the distance from $\mu$ to the center of mass of $A$, $\hat{r}$ points from the center of mass of $A$ to $\mu$, and $M_A \equiv \sum_\alpha m_\alpha$ is the total mass of $A$.  Thus, the force between object $A$ and a point mass is *approximately* what we would expect from two point masses separated by the distance $r$.

The proof of the attraction between two extended objects $A$ and $B$ works similarly.  If we now imagine assembling a large number of point  masses $\mu$ into an extended object $B$, the force felt by each individual mass will be slightly different.  However, if all of these point masses are very far from the object $A$, then the individual gravitational accelerations they feel will be *approximately* the same.  (Think about how the gravitational acceleration near the surface of the earth is approximately constant in magnitude and direction;  it's the same idea here.)  Thus, the object $B$ will act as though it's a point mass so long as sufficiently far away from $A$.